# Thunar still shows SD card after it's been removed

Tags: mount, xfce, sd-card, thunar

Sometimes after I unmount a SD card and then remove it from the SD card slot, Thunar still displays it in the **Devices** menu, and if I insert a new card, it won't be mounted.

The disk does not show in the mtab file and the only way I can find out of this is to restart the computer.

Is there any way to prevent this, or resolve it when it happens without restarting the computer?

Answer (score 2):

I just realized the problem was caused by unmounting while a file on the disk still in use. I closed the program that was using the file and problem was solved.